# For rational functions, do we always know the order of the pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

In general, if we are faced with a rational function, is the order of the pole always determined by the power to which the pole is raised?

FOr example,

$$ f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{(z-2)(z-5)z^2}$$

Do we know that $z=0$ is a pole of order $0$? Or must we check that it is not an essential singularity or a removatlbe singularity by expanding into a Laurent Series?

I wonder if this is true for for rational functions.  I can find counter examples for other functions, but not for rational functions.

Comment: rational functions don't have essential singularities

Comment: right on, yes thank you.

Comment: but do we still need to check the orderof the pole?  or do we know it is of order $2$ if it is a rational function?

Comment: The order is it's multiplicity as a root in the denominator minus it's multiplicitly as a root in the numerator.